how can I create s3 bucket on ceph?
root@tuy:/# ceph --version
ceph version 17.2.7 (b12291d110049b2f35e32e0de30d70e9a4c060d2) quincy (stable)

ceph is deployed on vmware
I can create s3 bucket from my ceph dashboard.
root@tuy:/# radosgw-admin bucket list
[
    "bucket1"
]

But I need to create it from cli. Is it possible?
rm is here, but not create function
root@tuy:/# radosgw-admin bucket --help
  bucket list                list buckets (specify --allow-unordered for
                             faster, unsorted listing)
  bucket limit check         show bucket sharding stats
  bucket link                link bucket to specified user
  bucket unlink              unlink bucket from specified user
  bucket stats               returns bucket statistics
  bucket rm                  remove bucket
  bucket check               check bucket index by verifying size and object count stats
  bucket check olh           check for olh index entries and objects that are pending removal
  bucket check unlinked      check for object versions that are not visible in a bucket listing 
  bucket chown               link bucket to specified user and update its object ACLs
  bucket reshard             reshard bucket
  bucket rewrite             rewrite all objects in the specified bucket
  bucket sync checkpoint     poll a bucket's sync status until it catches up to its remote
  bucket sync disable        disable bucket sync
  bucket sync enable         enable bucket sync
  bucket radoslist           list rados objects backing bucket's objects

I found solutions for developers https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/s3/bucketops/
Also I found  "ceph osd crush add-bucket" command but I don't understand what is it
Need help
I cant add tags radosgw and s3

have you configured s3cmd ?

A "crush bucket" ist something within ceph, it has nothing to do with S3 buckets. Does this answer your question?
